# How to embed controls dynamically in existing template based on datatype (conditions) in Angular?

Tags: angular, templates

Using Angular4:
In my existing component's template, I have various if cases. In future these if casses will increase. So I want to use factory class which will provide the template depending on my datatype and then I want to insert this template in my existing template. So that in future I dont need to change my parent template all I need to do is to insert corresponding template in factory class and that template will get added automatically in my parent template.
Any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Shared Services** method for a factory and create a separate directive for every child template referring to a parent template.

Comment: Since I am novice in angular2, could you please provide some example for the same for better understanding?